# Html versão do IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Tive a ver uns códigos num site e gostaria de saber se é possivel fazer Isto
Aqui qualquer IE fica emulado com o 8

Agora a minha duvida é:
É possivel criar esse código da seguinte forma. 
Se o utilizador abrir a página com o IE9 emulado com o 8, Se abrir com o 10 ou 11 emula com o 10 ou 11, Se abrir com o 8 Emula com o 8

Comment: @rray acho que ele quer saber se dá para o utilizador duma página (criada por ti) ao abrir a página http://www.meusite.com se pode ficar sempre emulado o IE8 por exemplo.

Comment: Quero emular dependendo do ie que se esta a usar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como você quer que o IE8, IE10 e IE11 mantenham o seu comportamento normal, acredito que o melhor a fazer é colocar um condicional para o IE9

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
<![endif]-->
```

Lembrando que você pode adicionar condições para verificar a versão do IE até o IE9.
A partir do IE10 esta verificação é ignorada (assim como o conteudo).

**EXTRA:**

as vezes tenho vontade de adicionar o seguinte trecho de codigo:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('Para continuar atualize o seu IE!');
        window.location.href = 'http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/internet-explorer/download-ie';
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Pois normal. As vezes nem é para atualizar o IE é para porem um browser como deve de ser. Já que o IE vai ser descontinuado